# customize categorical axis labels (allowing duplicated labels) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a plot based on a dataframe with categorical X axis and multiple types of elements to draw, and only certain records are supposed to be placed on the plot:

```
dt1 <- fread('
    ID label   type value
    a1     A    bar   40 
    a1     A  point   30 
    b1     B    bar   50 
    b1     B  point   20 
    c1     C    bar   30 
    c1     C  point   45 
    c1     C  point   20 
    d1     D  point   30 
    d1     D  point   35 
    e1     E   none   50 
    a2     A    bar   45 
    a2     A  point   30 
    ')

# I want some custom order on the plot,
# here it will be   b1 - c1 - a1 - d1 - a2
dt1[, ID:=factor(ID, levels=unique(ID[order(value)]))]
```

(in this sample dataset I show only "point" and "bar" but in the real one I have more elements and additional columns used to decide whether to plot them)

The plot I want should be something like this:
[image: desired result]
You can see that labels are taken from another column in my dataframe, but they are not unique, so I can't simply use `aes(x=label)`. I guess I should add something like `scale_x_discrete(labels=???)` but not sure what should I put there.
In general, I am actually interested in two different types of solution: a) map labels to another column of the original dataset; b) somehow extract "internal" labels from the ggplot object and process them with simple things like `gsub()`, `toupper()` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt2 <- dt1[type != "none"]
dt2[, ID:=factor(ID, levels=unique(ID[order(value)]))]

ggplot(dt2, aes(x=ID,y=value))+
  geom_col(data=dt1[type=='bar',], alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(data=dt1[type=='point',], size=5, col='red') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dt2$ID), labels = function(x) dt2$label[match(x, dt2$ID)])
```

[image]

To answer your second point, given the current values of the x axis, you could also use something like:

```
scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dt2$ID), labels = function(x) gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", toupper(x)))
```